# Azure AD B2C custom policy not returning account lockout error (50053)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, password-protection, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I was testing AD B2C smart lockout feature following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management#view-locked-out-accounts).

My current smart lockout settings:
[image]

The sign-ins log showed that the account I used for testing is successfully locked:
[image]

However, in my sign-in page that is using custom policy, the error is not showing my account being temporarily locked despite having Localized String in my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml:

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfUserAccountLocked">#Your account is temporarily locked to prevent unauthorized use. Try again later.</LocalizedString>
```

The error message in sign-in page is always `The username or password provided in the request are invalid`:

[image]

May I know what could be the direction for me to troubleshoot this/ common causes to this?

EDIT: From Chrome developer tools, the call is always returning the same `The username or password provided in the request are invalid.` response even if the lockout threshold is exceeded.
[image]

Comment: Can you do a successful login at all?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT yes, I can successfully login and issue JWT with the correct password.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming, we are aware of the issue and are working on it.

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT, thanks for your confirmation and help! To supplement, the issue is reproducible on different tenants in different subscriptions. The only thing being shared is the custom policies.(which the tenant name and IEF ids... are replaced). I hope it can give more clues, but unfortunately I cannot share the custom policy here due to some non-disclosure agreement. Kindly let me know what other information could be useful to you and I will check if I can supply. Many thanks again.

Comment: We know what the cause is, but we have not fixed it just yet. If you really need a quick fix, remove the metadata item "grant_type" from login-noninteractive technical profile. This might have untoward side effects that are not yet known.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thanks for your help! We can confirm that the temp fix proposed is working. Looking forward to your perm fix. :)

Comment: Hi, @ray. Try to use unique passwords, see the similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea917a58-cdba-412d-a24d-1e4d1b90f17a/b2c-account-locking-is-not-working-properly?forum=AzureSecurityCenter).

Comment: Thanks @JasSuri-MSFT, what (if any) are the repercussion of making that change? Are there any side-effects to be aware of?

Comment: No known bad side effects at this time.

Comment: Any update on this Jas? Is it possible to check account lock status during sign in journey and control messaging and behavior? Our requirement is to not accept correct password during lock out and always display "Your account is currently locked. Wait X minutes before trying" - I tried using AAD read user by email address but not sure which claim to check and how to stop the journey from executing following steps...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with this exact message not appearing when a user is locked out. Except that I am not using any custom user policies, so the quick fix suggested by Jas was not relevant for me.

I found that I was able to get it working by enabling custom languages for the user flow, and overriding the default value for that error message:

```
{
  "ElementType": "ErrorMessage",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "UserMessageIfUserAccountLocked",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Your account is temporarily locked to prevent unauthorized use. Try again later."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort first. Although I do not work on the ADB2C project anymore, I doubt that the team will switch from custom policy to user flow. AFAIK, the quick fix provided from @JasSuri-MSFT is still valid and in-force, though a perm fix will be even better :)