# Account Lockout in Azue B2C Custom Policy is not Working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, password-protection, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have configured a Sign in custom policy in Azure B2C. Customer wants lock out the account if they enter wrong password three times during sign in.
I have tried Password Protection in Azure Azure B2C authentication. Follows below document to configure the password protection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management

I have entered the password many times and it still showing "The username or password provided in the request are invalid"

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance!

[Password Protection Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE7Qk.png)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802966/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-not-returning-account-lockout-error-50053?noredirect=1#comment120358250_65802966

Comment: I have tried this. Its not showing any error message when I remove grant_type" from login-noninteractive technical profile.

Comment: Make sure to follow the testing instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management#testing-the-password-protection-settings

Comment: Yes, I have followed all the instructions same as in Microsoft document. When I check sign in audit, it showing correct message. But in the front end, its showing The username or password provided in the request are invalid"

Comment: @Ramya had the same issue, someone pointed out in the comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802966/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-not-returning-account-lockout-error-50053). Works for me, but the behaviour is .. strange, not the first time when working with B2C ;)